# Extracting shrubs from DSM

Tags: dem

I want to find to find single entity shrubs. I thought I could use a DSM and DTM, though, it seems like it is only possible to find trees (since the trees are covering the shrubs)...

Is there a way to do this using QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Normalize the points, extract points with a height above ground in some interval

Answer (score 1):

You could define classes for shrub and tree vegetation and reclassify the pixels by these values and extract the shrub vegetation in the end. For example, shrub vegetation (1,5 - 5 m). This would result in a raster with unique values and not a stretched raster. But you cannot really define where shrubs are covered by the tree layer. Only if you’re using Lidar data you have some more information about what lays beneath the tree canopy.